# python subprocess check_call insists that a file exist

Tags: python, subprocess, file-not-found

I have looked online, and particularly here in Stackoverflow, and I have not found this particular problem.  I am trying to use the python subprocess module to run a command line program within my application.  The purpose of the script is to create the last file in the arguments list.  One needs to provide the file name to the script, so it can be created.  The file is not supposed to exist already.  I create the command:

```
command = ['/path_to_the_executable/bin/kraken', '-i', '/path_to_the_scans/Scans/4.jpg', '4.tif', 'binarize']
```

Then I hand the command to subprocess.check_call:

```
output = check_call(command, cwd=output_path)
```

When I run this full command apart from python, directly on the command line, it creates the file in the correct directory.  It works.  When I run it within subprocess.check_call, it says that last file does not exist, and refuses to execute.  But the last file is not supposed to exist!  It is supposed to be created in this process.  Why does check_call insist on this, and how can I turn it off?  Or is there another option? Or am I doing something wrong?

I have also tried an alternative method, that is to create a full path to the new, as-yet-uncreated file, and leave off the cwd=output_path.  The script, when I run it directly on the command line, works with this format as well, the full path to the output file.  But in python, it complains in the same way...the file or directory does not exist.

I have also tried with subprocess call, and that fails in the same way: FileNotFoundError.

Please help me!  I am frustrated, and quite disappointed in my beloved Python just now...

Info about kraken can be found here: http://kraken.re/  It is a python-based command line utility.

Herer is the error message:

```
FileNotFoundError at /ocr/kraken_binarize/

[Errno 2] No such file or directory: 
'/path_to_output_directory/ocr_textmining_samples/Scans_300_dpi/4.tif'

Request Method:     POST
Request URL:    http://127.0.0.1:8000/ocr/kraken_binarize/
Django Version:     1.10.5
Exception Type:     FileNotFoundError
Exception Value:    

[Errno 2] No such file or directory: 
'/path_to_output_directory/ocr_textmining_samples/Scans_300_dpi/4.tif'

Exception Location:     /path_to_python/opencv-
ocr/lib/python3.6/subprocess.py in _execute_child, line 1326
```

ls -al /path_to_output_directory/ocr_textmining_samples/Scans_300_d‌​pi shows that I am the owner.

```
ls -al Dokumente/ocr_textmining_samples/Scans_300_dpi/
insgesamt 8
drwxrwxr-x  2 pwarner pwarner 4096 Jul 27 12:59 .
drwxrwxr-x 13 pwarner pwarner 4096 Jul 27 13:00 ..
```

Here is ls -al for the eclipse workspace directory:

```
ls -al workspace-python/ocr_textmining_server/data/test/
insgesamt 100
drwxrwxr-x 2 pwarner pwarner  4096 Jul 27 14:01 .
drwxrwxr-x 6 pwarner pwarner  4096 Jul 27 13:59 ..
-rw-rw-r-- 1 pwarner pwarner 90915 Jul 27 14:01 4.tif
```

Comment: Could you post the exact error message you get, please.

Comment: And what is "kraken"?  Is it a compiled binary, python script, shell script or something else?

Comment: Thanks, @Hannu! I have posted answers to your questions in the question above.

Comment: And the file mentioned in the error message exists, or if it is the output file, path /path_to_output_directory/ocr_textmining_samples/Scans_300_dpi/ exists?

Comment: The path exists, and works from the command line.

Comment: Hm, it exists, but is it unwritable?  I will test and let you know.

Comment: Hmm... weird. what does ls -al /path_to_output_directory/ocr_textmining_samples/Scans_300_dpi show? Do you have write permission to the directory, or is there already a file with the same name?  The error seems like a file system access issue, not a Python call issue.

Comment: You are right, @Hannu!  Somehow the directory was not writable from django.  Strange.  I switched to use a directory inside the eclipse workspace, and it wrote the file.  Whew.  Thank you very much.  You are right, it was not a Python call issue.  It is strange, though, both directories are in my home directory.